# How to count 2 rows between 2 numbers in the same column

Tags: sql

```
SELECT (COUNT (*))
FROM dbo.DIM_Calendar
WHERE (IdCalendar = 20190916  AND IdCalendar = 20191031)
```

The IDCalendar its an INT type, I would like to know the count between those 2 IdCalendars.

Comment: Kindly tag your Question with the database you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you're missing information. But what I understand what you want is as simple as use `>=` and `<=`

```
 SELECT (COUNT (*))
 FROM dbo.DIM_Calendar
 WHERE (IdCalendar >= 20190916  AND IdCalendar <= 20191031)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BETWEEN`

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.DIM_Calendar
WHERE IdCalendar BETWEEN 20190916 AND 20191031
```